# memory allocation in javascript

Tags: javascript, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I know that the memory allocation in js differs from languages like c++ language
when I write like below

```
var arr=[]
arr[10000]=34;
```

or write

```
var arr=[]
arr[10]=34;
```

or

```
 var arr=new Array(10000)
 arr[10]=34;
```

does they take the same memory? only one block(because of number 34) thanks in advance

Comment: From what i know, they should all have approximately the same memory footprint, which is constant array object overhead and one element.

Comment: Use typed arrays if you are concerned with that. Otherwise it depend on the implementation.